# gt table in R Markdown not being outputted

Tags: r, gt

I just discovered the gt library and was excited to try it out but no matter what I did, the tables keep being outputted as a function???

The code is the same on the homepage of the gt website, the gt(x) is literally being processed as a function as we can see from the picture. I updated all my packages and even installed the developer version as well but I keep getting this function output
[gt table function output, no table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83r0s.png)

Comment: Hi Minhaz, Glad you got your issue sorted! Please add a bit more to make your issue and solution reproducible so they can save someone else that fun hour!

Comment: If you want to save hours in the future, try deleting any existing `.Rdata` files, not saving any in the future and  running code in a clean programming environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies, turns out there's also a function called "gt" in the expss package I had loaded that interfered with it, looks like I'm not getting my hour back from trying to troubleshoot this lol

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `gtsave` function and save as a `.png` and it will output. For example, here is a plot that I generated with the following code:

```
{r mOS Table Generation, fig.dim=c(6,8)}
mostable <- mosdf %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-Dose) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(title = "Median Overall Survival (mOS)", subtitle = md("*Subjects Treated from REDACTED*")) %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "95% Confidence Interval",
    columns = c(5:6)) %>%
  cols_align(align = "center") %>%
  tab_style(cell_text(weight = "bold"),
            locations = list(cells_title(groups = c("title", "subtitle")), 
                             cells_column_spanners(spanners = everything()), 
                             cells_column_labels(columns = c(1:4)))) %>%
  tab_style(cell_text(style = "italic"),
            locations = cells_row_groups(groups = everything()))

setwd(output)
gtsave(mostable, "mostable.png", vwidth = 1500, vheight = 1000)
```

Here is how it looks the R Markdown when knitted to Word:

[image: gtsaveexample]

Note, even though I have the dimension statement in the chunk code, `gtsave` is dependent on `webshot`, so the `vwidth` and `vheight` control the size of the output to the working directory. Most of the time the output size is fine, but I am still working through how to change the output size. Most of the time I just manually do it, but prefer to not have to update the output. I am going to ask another question, so I will link if there is a solution.